# Angular: Conditionally importing module not working with AoT

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular9

I am trying to conditionally import a module based on if the firebase API key is specified in my environment file or not. When there are no API key, I don't want to load the Firebase modules. When the values are set in the environment file, I want to load both `AngularFireAuthModule` and `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`.

Here's how I've been doing it in Angular 7:

```ts
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

import { AlwaysLoggedInProvider } from './identity/providers/always-logged-in-provider';
import { AuthHttpInterceptor } from './interceptors/auth-http-interceptor';
import { FirebaseProvider } from './identity/providers/firebase-provider';
import { IdentityProviderToken } from './identity/identity-provider';

const firebaseConfig = environment.firebase;
export const identityProvider = isFirebaseConfigured() ? FirebaseProvider : AlwaysLoggedInProvider;

export function identityProviderModules() {
  if (isFirebaseConfigured) {
    return [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), AngularFireAuthModule];
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

export function isFirebaseConfigured() {
  return firebaseConfig && 'apiKey' in firebaseConfig && firebaseConfig.apiKey !== '';
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [...identityProviderModules()],
  providers: [
    { provide: IdentityProviderToken, useClass: identityProvider },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

Now, after upgrading to Angular 9, everything seems to work, but when compiling I am getting these errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/authentication/authentication.module.ts:30:12 - error NG1010: Value at position 0 in the NgModule.imports of AuthenticationModule is not a reference: [object Object]

30   imports: [...identityProviderModules()],
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/services/authentication/authentication.module.ts:40:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of LoginModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?

40 export class AuthenticationModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/login/login.module.ts:26:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

26 export class LoginModule {}
```

I've looked around and I noticed that this is caused by the AoT compilation (which I want to keep) and is because I have a condition inside `identityProviderModules()`. I've found some solutions for providers but since I am working with imports, I don't think it's much use to me unless there is a way to convert those modules to be providers.

What would be the correct way to conditionally import modules based on a value in the environment file? How can I make AoT compile this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded from 7 to 10 and had a similar issue with similar errors.
I couldn't get a ternary working with the aot compiler, so I ended up creating an array of imports (myImports in the example below), and then an if statement checking my condition and pushing into the array.
I then passed the array into the imports: section of the module annotation and that worked out for me.

```
const firebaseConfig = environment.firebase;

export const identityProvider = isFirebaseConfigured() ? FirebaseProvider : AlwaysLoggedInProvider;

// Other imports that are not dynamic can still be included here:
const myImports = [];
export function identityProviderModules() {
    if (isFirebaseConfigured) {
        myImports.push(AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), AngularFireAuthModule);
    }

    export function isFirebaseConfigured() {
        return firebaseConfig && 'apiKey' in firebaseConfig && firebaseConfig.apiKey !== '';
    }

    @NgModule({
        imports: myImports,
        providers: [
            { provide: IdentityProviderToken, useClass: identityProvider },
            {
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,
                multi: true,
            },
        ],
    })
    export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

I'm not sure how related it is, but the module I was conditionally importing was also missing the annotations that are now required:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ....
```